# installation of Bower : getting npm ERR

Tags: npm, bower

I have node and nodenv installed on my Ubuntu 16.04
I want to install bower

```
npm install -g bower
```

I am getting this  :

> npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop
>   working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent
>   this by migrating to Yarn:
>   https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
>   npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-94-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/home/mypc/.nodenv/versions/4.6.0/bin/node" "/home/mypc/.nodenv/versions/4.6.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
>   "bower"
>   npm ERR! node v4.6.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
>   npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-4594-c12fe2a2/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.2.tgz
>   npm ERR! Expected: adf53529c8d4af02ef24fb8d5341c1419d33e2f7
>   npm ERR! Actual:   ca90d0b92af2557a3f8e9116ba83b3fc4ad7828
>   npm ERR! From: https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.2.tgz
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

Answer (score 0):

The npm client is unable to verify the downloaded file from the npm registry:

```
shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-4594-c12fe2a2/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.2.tgz
Expected: adf53529c8d4af02ef24fb8d5341c1419d33e2f7
Actual: ca90d0b92af2557a3f8e9116ba83b3fc4ad7828
```

## How to fix?

- If you have a corporate proxy in between, make sure it doesn't modify the content of your downloaded files.
- If there is no proxy involved, retry the installation.